# Написал вычисления по обратной польской нотации. Но если умножение идет за делением результат не сходится с калькулятором

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Подозреваю что у них разные приоритеты друг над другом. И что с этим делать?

```js
// Берем выражение 20*(47-60/-3+9)+978/6+(32-21*3) Получаем 1652
// Берем 20*(47-60/-3+9)+978/6*(32-21*3)
// По калькулятору нужно -3533, но дает -42873
//let s = '20*(47-60/-3+9)+978/6+(32-21*3)';
let s = '20*(41-60/-3)+978/6*(32-21*3)'
// разделяем на числа, скобки и знаки
let ss = s.split('');
let st1 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < ss.length - 1; i++) {
  if ((!isNaN(ss[i]) && isNaN(ss[i + 1])) || (isNaN(ss[i]) && !isNaN(ss[i + 1]))) {
    ss.splice(i + 1, 0, ' ');
    i++;
  }
}
sss = ss.join('').split(' ');
for (var i = 0; i < sss.length; i++) {
  if (isNaN(sss[i])) {
    t = sss[i].split('');
    sss[i] = t;
  }
}
sss = sss.flat();
// отрицательные
if (sss[0] == '-') {
  let changeFirstABS = -sss[1];
  sss[1] = changeFirstABS;
  sss.splice(0, 1);
}
for (var i = 0; i < sss.length; i++) {
  if (!isNaN(sss[i]) && sss[i - 1] == '-' && isNaN(sss[i - 2])) {
    t = -sss[i];
    sss[i] = t;
    sss.splice(i - 1, 1);
  }
}
// отрицательные
for (var i = 0; i < sss.length; i++) {
  if (!isNaN(sss[i])) {
    sss[i] = parseInt(sss[i])
  }
}
console.log(sss);
// из строки получили массив положительных и отрицательных чисел, скобок и знаков
// теперь переводим его из инфиксной записи в постфиксную
ops = {
  '+': 1,
  '-': 1,
  '/': 2,
  '*': 2
};
s = sss;
stack = [];
out = [];
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  if (!isNaN(s[i])) {
    out.push(s[i]);
  }
  if (isNaN(s[i])) {
    a = stack[stack.length - 1];
    if (stack.length == 0) {
      stack.push(s[i])
    } else {
      if (s[i] == '(' || a == '(') {
        stack.push(s[i])
      }
      if (ops[a] >= ops[s[i]]) {
        out.push(a);
        stack.pop();
        openBracket = stack.lastIndexOf('(');
        n = stack.splice(openBracket + 1).reverse().join('');
        out.push(n);
        out = out.flat();
        stack.push(s[i]);
      }
      if (ops[a] < ops[s[i]]) {
        stack.push(s[i]);
      }
      if (s[i] == ')') {
        while (stack[stack.length - 1] != '(') {
          out.push(stack[stack.length - 1]);
          stack.pop();
        }
        stack.pop();
      }
    }
  }
}
if (stack.length != 0) {
  while (stack.length > 0) {
    out.push(stack[stack.length - 1]);
    stack.pop();
  }
}
for (var i = 0; i < out.length; i++) {
  if (out[i] == '') {
    out.splice(i, 1);
    i--;
  }
}
console.log('out is', out);
// перевели в постфиксную запись
// обратная польская нотация и стек
let stack2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < out.length; i++) {
  if (!isNaN(out[i])) {
    stack2.push(out[i])
  } else {
    if (out[i] == '*') {
      var res = stack2[stack2.length - 2] * stack2[stack2.length - 1];
      stack2.splice(stack2.length - 2);
      stack2.push(res);
    }
    if (out[i] == '+') {
      var res = stack2[stack2.length - 2] + stack2[stack2.length - 1];
      stack2.splice(stack2.length - 2);
      stack2.push(res);
    }
    if (out[i] == '-') {
      var res = stack2[stack2.length - 2] - stack2[stack2.length - 1];
      stack2.splice(stack2.length - 2);
      stack2.push(res);
    }
    if (out[i] == '/') {
      var res = stack2[stack2.length - 2] / stack2[stack2.length - 1];
      stack2.splice(stack2.length - 2);
      stack2.push(res);
    }
  }
}
console.log(res);
// подсчитали
```

Comment: Попробуйте разобраться сначала на выражениях попроще.

Comment: в обратной польской нотации нет приоритетов, все выполняется в порядке поступления операторов

Comment: У тебя проблема в том, что ты неправильно переводишь в обратную польскую запись, поэтому и результат неверный. Посмотри в дубликате, как минимум два рабочих примера.